# Run Bash scripts in folder all at the same time

Tags: bash, scripts

Let's suppose I have five Bash (`.sh`) scripts in a folder (`my_folder`), and they are named as follows:

```
script_1.sh
script_2.sh
script_3.sh
script_4.sh
script_5.sh
```

How can I write a sixth Bash script or just a one liner that will start running all these scripts together?

I need the five scripts to start running all together at the same time and not one after the other.

Comment: related: [Running a directory full of .sh files with one command](https://askubuntu.com/q/910454/3712)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GNU `parallel` is perfect for this sort of thing. Install with `sudo apt install parallel` and then:

```
parallel -j0 ::: my_folder/*sh
```

The `-j` controls how many processes t run in parallel, and `-j0` means "all of them". Set it to another value (e.g. `-j20`) to run the scripts in batches instead.

Comment: note: there is also the `parallel` command from the `moreutils` package. The example usage: `parallel -j 20 -- my_folder/*.sh` (Unlike GNU `parallel`, `-j0` would run the scripts one at a time).

Comment: @jfs good point. But note that `sudo apt install parallel` will replace the file in `/usr/bin/parallel` with the one from GNU parallel. So as long as you install it, as my answer suggests, it should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I'd found out it the hard way when trying unsuccessfully `parallel` commands from the manual while writing my answer to suggest GNU parallel.

Answer (score 10):

To run all scripts at the same time (in parallel) use:

```bash
script_1.sh &
script_2.sh &
script_3.sh &
script_4.sh &
script_5.sh &
```

To run the one after the other (sequentially) use:

```bash
script_1.sh &&
script_2.sh &&
script_3.sh &&
script_4.sh &&
script_5.sh
```

---

### Enhancement for comments

If you have 200 scripts you want to run at the same time (which might bog down the machine BTW) use this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for Script in my_folder/*.sh ; do
    echo bash "$Script" &
done
```

Set the script attributes to executable with the command:

```bash
chmod a+x /path/to/script.sh
```

The first time you run the script it will only echo the names of the 200 scripts it will be executing. When you are happy the right names are being selected edit the script and change this line:

```bash
    echo bash "$Script" &
```

to:

```bash
    bash "$Script" &
```

---

There are three ways you can call a bash script from another as answered here:

- [How to call shell script from another shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352851/how-to-call-shell-script-from-another-shell-script)

> 1. Make the other script executable, add the `#!/bin/bash` line at the top, and the path where the file is to the `$PATH` environment
>      variable. Then you can call it as a normal command;
> 2. Or call it with the source command (alias is .) like this: `source /path/to/script`;
> 3. Or use the bash command to execute it: `/bin/bash /path/to/script`;

In OP's case one or more of the 200 scripts did not contain the shebang `#!/bin/bash` first line in the file. As such option 3. had to be used.

---

### 200 Scripts running at the same time

A comment has been raised about whether they are "running at the same time". On a typical 8 CPU system 25 scripts will be sharing one CPU at the same time but only one one script will execute at a time until it's time slice (measured in milliseconds) runs out. Then the next job will receive its fair share of milliseconds, then the next job, etc., etc.

In loose terms we can say 200 jobs are running "concurrently" but not "simultaneously" across 8 CPUs which equates to 25 jobs per CPU:

[image: thread states.png]

Above image and comments below from [Linux kernel scheduler](https://helix979.github.io/jkoo/post/os-scheduler/)

[image: time slice.png]

Comment: thank you..the thing is that in my real case I have more than 200 scripts to run. so is there any way I can run all of them with a single command (i.e. without writing their file names)?

Comment: @aaaaa I've changed the answer for 200 scripts.

Comment: thanks. it works.. the only thing I had to add to your last line was 'bash'. otherwise I get 'permission denied'.

Comment: @aaaaa Do you actually prefer that all 200+ scripts to run at the same time, or would you rather have some smaller number (say, 10) run at a time, with the others queued to run when one or more of them finishes and the number of currently running scripts drops below that number? (If you're interested in such solutions, I suggest editing your question with information about how many scripts you have, how long they tend to take to run, what kind of work they do, and so forth.)

Comment: @aaaaa Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the answer to include `bash` prefix to calling the script.

Comment: Except that there's a bit of a caveat with "at the same time".  You won't actually be running more simultaneous processes than there are processors.

Comment: @jamesqf Good point. I've updated answer with time slices. I upvoted your only post in three years as a reward :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a tool for this, read `man run-parts`.

For example, I do:

```
 run-parts ${visorhome}/pbackup.d/
```

in my Palm Pilot backup script. `${visorhome}/pbackup.d/`:

```
01PopulateJpilot  02Extract_Pedometer  03URLs  04google  05Books  06Weight  07Sec  08Bkgm 50hardlinks
```

Comment: @eliah-kagan Running "more than 200 scripts" "at the same time" seems unwise. It might be a good way to stress test a system

Comment: Good point. I do think you may still want to mention that `run-parts` executes the scripts sequentially rather than all at once as the OP requested. You're right, though, that running 200 scripts at once is unlikely to perform the same as running 5--and even if running them all at once doesn't cause any problems, it may still be unnecessary. I've [commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156434/run-bash-scripts-in-folder-all-at-the-same-time#comment1924227_1156436) to suggest the OP clarify their preferences in this regard.

Comment: `run-parts` won't run the scripts (they have a dot in the name: `my_folder/*.sh`

Comment: `run-parts` has  [very_ specific](https://superuser.com/a/719493/151431) file name requirements for some strange reason. It won't launch file names with extensions, so I'm afraid this won't work here.

Answer (score 1):

To run all `*.sh` scripts in `my_folder` directory at the same time using `xargs`:

```
$ ls my_folder/*.sh | xargs -P0 -n1 bash
```

To limit the number of concurrently executed scripts to `10`:

```
$ ls my_folder/*.sh | xargs -P10 -n1 bash
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to use the output of `ls` in a script. Using `find` is much safer. It's the very first item here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: @Joe in general, it is true. I don't see issues in this particular case.

Comment: That's because you already know about it. People coming here later might not.

Comment: @Joe don't follow dogma blindly. Think for yourself than one option is better than another what are trade offs in your case.

Comment: It's not a dogma. I'm alergic to those.  But I've seen the stuff ls can emit.  Parsing human readable output isn't reliable. There's no incentive for developers to keep

Comment: The format constant. Your code works. That's not an issue.

Comment: The problem is not so much `ls` (without options) as it is `xargs`: Try `touch my_folder/" not run.sh"`

Comment: @OleTange yes, scripts that have spaces in their name are out-of-scope for the solution (obviously, it can be extended by providing additional arguments (`-0` option?) but I wouldn't bother  for  a simple one-liner that is supposed to be executed interactively (the use case: you are running your own scripts).